# I've gotten access to Donovan's room. Now what?

Tags: why-am-i-dead-at-sea

Paulo's clue at the moment is for Gwen to gain access to Donovan's room. Having done so, I've had her examine the object on his dresser, his bed, two piles of surveillance equipment, his computer, and the boxes in the corner, but while it's all very puzzling, looking around isn't accomplishing anything—I'd guess I need to access the computer, but nobody I've tried can make any headway. I brought Sue in, since she knows what the item on the dresser is, but while she comments on it, she won't take it. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but for those who were stuck like you and me - after Gwen has investigated the things in Donovan's room, she'll be able to talk about it to the person who oh-so-subtly used reverse-psychology to have her look in the first place.